# RuntimeError: ERR unknown command 'HMSET'

Tags: carto

I am trying to create a user, say **dev**, for cartodb running in local machine. When i run the script create_dev_user

```
sh script/create_dev_user dev
```

It produces this `RuntimeError: ERR unknown command 'HMSET'` error. I am on ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: What version of Redis have you installed?

Comment: @luisico redis-server version is **2.1**. It have checked, and found that redis version needs to be > 2.0.

Comment: upgraded redis version to 2.2. Problem solved.

Comment: Could you add your comment as a response of your question? This way the rest of the community will be able to see the question as answered :)

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading redis version solved the issue.

Comment: please clarify your answer to your own question in more details instead of a few words. and consider marking this as the correct answer to your own question.